# How do I turn off 3d in an emedded youtube url played in JWplayer

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer6

JW player turnes on 3d in an embedded youtube video in JWplayer automatically. Is there any way to turn it off in the url?

```
<div id="jwElement" ></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
jwplayer("jwElement").setup({
    file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVb0DiskHhs",
    width: 640,
height:320,
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: JW Player isn't turning the 3d effect on or off - the YouTube URL simply calls up the video with 3d enabled. I've done some hunting, and so far I haven't found a URL query string that disables it. Makes me suspect there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is set the player's "primary" variable to "flash", and it might override this setting. YouTube now defaults to HTML5 mode for 6.9, which I suspect might be what's going on here.

It looks like with some further investigation, the video is only 3d if the original video on YouTube has 3d enabled by default. This also seems to happen on a browser by browser basis. For example, in my Firefox, the original video on YouTube had 3d enabled, but when I checked Chrome, it wasn't enabled, and thus, the JW Player also displayed the video in non 3D mode. I wrote a ticket yesterday in our bug tracker about this, I will update it that it also happens in Flash mode.

Comment: Nope. Makes no difference - you still get the 3d version.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I am going to update my answer.